# динамическое добавление компонентом vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть код

```
 var app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {},
     methods: {
         v_add: function () {
              $('#drap').prepend('<auth-input></auth-input>');
         }
    },
    components: {
         'auth-input': {
              data: function () {},
              template: '<input class = "authinput"/></div>' }
     }
   });
```

Он не работает, всмысле добавляет просто `<auth-input></auth-input>`, а не компонент. В доках пишет, что компоненты нужно инициализовать до корневого app.
Вопрос. Можно ли как то заставить этот код работать?

Comment: Прямо скажем, ваш код весьма странен. _ всмысле добавляет просто <auth-input></auth-input>_ потому что у вас в коде так написано. Не очень понятно зачем вы Jquery тут применяете.  Совсем недавно читал документацию Vue.js точно помню что там написано как объявлять компоненты и вставлять их.
Чтоб прям подсказка - компонент вы вставите если он будет описан в template либо в функции render

Comment: Может я чего то не понимаю. Компонент работает нормально вот так <div id = "app"><auth-input></auth-input></div>. Но мне нужно вставлять его не сразу, при нажатии на кнопку, поэтому и использую jquery.

Comment: Задача  фрейморвка отслеживать состояния какой либо модели и соотвествующим образом отрисовывать компоненты. Черзе Jquery вы попросту вставляете тег, но не компонент. Вам нужно изменить к этому подход. 
Смотрите. В вашем корневом компоненте в template вы пишете нужный шаблон и вставляете такую штуковину как `<auth-input v-if="isShowInput"></auth-input>` . Описываете объект в data. А на клик вы вешаете обработчик которые меняет значение объекта с ключем isShowInput значение меняет а противоположное. Фреймворк сам увидит изменение и отрисует либо не отрисует ваш компонент.

Answer (score -2):

Давайте я оформлю комментарий ответом. 
Если мы берет Vue.js то мы должны понимать основополагающие концепции этого прекрасного инструмента.

Если быть кратким, то Vue берет на себя всю ответственность за слежением изменения и вывода модели согласно написанным вами же компонентов и условий их появления.

Чтобы быть понятнее. Представьте что у вас есть некий объект в корневом компоненте. Вы этот объект описываете в `data`, т.е. вашем примере вы описываете что то похожее -

```
   el: '#app',
   template: {'<auth-input v-if="mydata.isShowInput"></auth-input>},
   methods: {
             changeShowInput: function () {
             this.mydata.isShowInput = !this.mydata.isShowInput
             }
         },
   data: {
           mydata: { isShowInput: false }
         }
   .......
```

Далее вы в template корневого элемента вставляете ваш компонент но с условием отображения. Vue посмотрит на данные вашего условия и увидит что в объекте с ключем isShowInput - false и не отобразит элемент.

Вашей задачей остается изменить это поле в объекте. Вы попросту можете создать компонент с ссылкой, который выполнит функцию changeShowInput, которая в свою очередь изменит в вашей модели соответствующий пункт. Vue сам увидит эти изменения и отрисует (или скроет) ваш компонент.

Что же происходит у вас в коде. Вы в коде через JQuery вставляете в DOM некий кастомный тег. Он валидный, однако Vue его не видит и видеть не может потому что он работает именно так, как работает, а ни как иначе.

Вам лишь остается создать компонент со ссылкой, и если это будет дочерний компонент - передать event родителю, если же нет - попросту вешайте обработчик на нужное вам событие и выполняйте изменение модели. Остальное Vue сделает за вас.